# как в docker-compose.yml сделать доступными переменные из .env если сам файл в другом каталоге '../.env' на винде

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-compose

ВОПРОС: Как сделать так чтобы переменная

- DB_PORT

была определена в момент вызова up, без указания --env-file

вариант при вызове работает:

```
docker-compose -f [file].yml --env-file ../.env up
```

вот так в [file].yml уже не работает:(.env не находит)
**(находит)из текуших ответов понял что это просто капирует переменные из .env(будут доступны в image) но доступ в самом .yml не дает**

```
env_file:
  - ../.env
```

полный файл:

```
version: 'v2.23.3-desktop.2'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:${SOFTWARE_VERSION_TAG}
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#:%7E:text=Use%20secrets%20instead.-,Compose%20file,-Substitute%20with%20an)

> The .env file should be placed at the root of the project directory
> next to your compose.yaml file.

При использовании параметра [--env-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#:%7E:text=Substitute%20with%20%2D%2Denv%2Dfile)

> The advantage of this method is that you can store the file anywhere
> and name it appropriately

Comment: should это типо(хорошо бы) но не 100% там.

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из [информации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#additional-information) должно быть так:

```
env_file:
  - path: ../.env
```

можно попробовать `./../.env`

Comment: вроде оба синтксиса корректны. Не так тоже не получается. Предположу что при запуске ../ это уже он внутри контейнера считает путь в линуховой среде

Answer (score 2):

У меня не воспроизводится.

Я сделал простой образ

```
FROM alpine

CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $TEXT"]
```

```
docker build -t myalpine .
```

Запускаю его из `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  alpine:
    image: myalpine
    env_file:
      - ../.env
```

Файл `../.env`

```
TEXT="Hello, .env!"
```

Запуск:

```
PS:docker> docker compose up
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                  docker:default
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network docker_default     Created                                                                              0.5s
 ✔ Container docker-alpine-1  Created                                                                              1.0s
Attaching to docker-alpine-1
docker-alpine-1  | Hello, .env!
docker-alpine-1 exited with code 0
```

Как видите, переменная подхватывается и выводится контейнером.

Версия докера `Server: Docker Desktop 4.25.1 (128006)`

Версия Windows:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Home
OS Version:                10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621
```

Comment: спасибо, из твоего кода понял что параметр env_file копирует переменные из .env а не просто указывает путь к файлу, внутри самого compose.yml к сажелению переменные среды все так же не доступны. Может так и должно работать. Шя исправлю вопрос.